# logger in ruby unit test startup or setup

Tags: ruby, unit-testing

I am writing some tests in ruby and have this question.

```
class MyTest < Test::Unit::TestCase
    LogFile = "test.log"
    Log= Logger.new(LogFile)

    def startup
       @log = Log
    end

    def shutdown
    end

    def setup
    end

   ....

end
```

I am trying to create a logger in startup, however, it does not work well. In the test cases, @log is nil.
I know I can put it in setup, however, I don't want to reassign it for every test case. Why it does not work? What is the correct way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`startup` should be used as a class method. There you could define a class variable like `@@log`.

If you want to use an instance variable `@log` you must fill it in `setup`.

Example:

```
require 'test/unit'
require 'logger'
class MyTest < Test::Unit::TestCase
    LogFile = "test.log"
    Log= Logger.new(LogFile)

    def self.startup
       @@log = Log
    end

    def setup
       @log = Log
    end

    def test_class_var
      assert_kind_of(Logger,@@log)
    end
    def test_instance_var
      assert_kind_of(Logger,@log)
    end

end
```

Comment: This is just what I want. So in this case, what about LogFile and Log? Are they considered as instance variable? Also, is it the recommended way to put test class instance and logger in startup?

Comment: Log and Logfile are constants. In the actual example there is no need to define @log or @@log, you could also use Log.